# Mappin over an array of objects to display it in React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React, and I been stuck here for a while now, the Middle.js component and table. I am trying to loop over array of objects from the data I am fetching. It is userPools array and display in a table poolProvidersname and then consequently rest of the data.

I am quite confused as to how do I do this?

Here is the the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-ellis-xrir4?file=/src/components/Table.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jumping from JS to markup on JSX  can bit a bit confusing at first

When iterating an array of objects for display purposes, what you want to do is return a JSX fragment for each item on your array.

So if you have an array that looks like this:

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Lucia', age: 20 }, { id: 2, name: 'Karina', age: 21 }, { id: 3, name: 'Maria', age: 22 }];
```

to display it in your component you would go like this:

```js
const Table = ({ data }) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) return null;
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {
        data.map(item => // notice how we jump straight back to JSX here
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>
              {item.name}
            </td>
            <td>
              {item.age}
            </td>
          </tr>)
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying to do that. But it always give me this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' . It shows for the first time and when I refresh it gives an error

Comment: @Alexandria I edited my answer to account for that. Your page probably takes some time to load the data, leaving the variable as undefined.

Comment: Also, ideally you would initialize the `data` variable as an array, so that even if the data didn't load yet, it would still be an array (with a map method) and would not error out.

Comment: Wow, I get it now, because it is taking time to load, it is giving an error.

Comment: If I can recommend one more thing: try typescript instead of just js. It would have immediately warned you of the type difference between undefined and array.

Comment: I am new to Typescript as well, I do plan to use it.